# Custom CssSelectorBuilder object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

I've developed task solution following a learning program:

```
class CssSelectorBuilder {
  constructor() {
    this.selectors = [{ selectorName: '', selector: '' }];
    this.order = ['', 'element', 'id', 'class', 'attr', 'pseudoClass', 'pseudoElement'];
  }

  element(value) {
    const it = new CssSelectorBuilder();
    it.selectors = this.selectors.slice();
    const prevSelector = it.selectors.pop();
    if (prevSelector.selectorName === 'element') {
      throw new Error('Element, id and pseudo-element should not occur more then one time inside the selector');
    }
    if (it.order.slice(2).includes(prevSelector.selectorName)) {
      throw new Error('Selector parts should be arranged in the following order: element, id, class, attribute, pseudo-class, pseudo-element');
    }
    it.selectors.push({ selectorName: 'element', selector: value });
    return it;
  }

  id(value) {
    const it = new CssSelectorBuilder();
    it.selectors = this.selectors.slice();
    const prevSelector = it.selectors.pop();
    if (prevSelector.selectorName === 'id') {
      throw new Error('Element, id and pseudo-element should not occur more then one time inside the selector');
    }
    if (it.order.slice(3).includes(prevSelector.selectorName)) {
      throw new Error('Selector parts should be arranged in the following order: element, id, class, attribute, pseudo-class, pseudo-element');
    }
    it.selectors.push(prevSelector);
    it.selectors.push({ selectorName: 'id', selector: `#${value}` });
    return it;
  }

  class(value) {
    const it = new CssSelectorBuilder();
    it.selectors = this.selectors.slice();
    const prevSelector = it.selectors.pop();
    if (it.order.slice(4).includes(prevSelector.selectorName)) {
      throw new Error('Selector parts should be arranged in the following order: element, id, class, attribute, pseudo-class, pseudo-element');
    }
    it.selectors.push(prevSelector);
    it.selectors.push({ selectorName: 'class', selector: `.${value}` });
    return it;
  }

  attr(value) {
    const it = new CssSelectorBuilder();
    it.selectors = this.selectors.slice();
    const prevSelector = it.selectors.pop();
    if (it.order.slice(5).includes(prevSelector.selectorName)) {
      throw new Error('Selector parts should be arranged in the following order: element, id, class, attribute, pseudo-class, pseudo-element');
    }
    it.selectors.push(prevSelector);
    it.selectors.push({ selectorName: 'attr', selector: `[${value}]` });
    return it;
  }

  pseudoClass(value) {
    const it = new CssSelectorBuilder();
    it.selectors = this.selectors.slice();
    const prevSelector = it.selectors.pop();
    if (it.order.slice(6).includes(prevSelector.selectorName)) {
      throw new Error('Selector parts should be arranged in the following order: element, id, class, attribute, pseudo-class, pseudo-element');
    }
    it.selectors.push(prevSelector);
    it.selectors.push({ selectorName: 'pseudoClass', selector: `:${value}` });
    return it;
  }

  pseudoElement(value) {
    const it = new CssSelectorBuilder();
    it.selectors = this.selectors.slice();
    const prevSelector = it.selectors.pop();
    if (prevSelector) {
      if (prevSelector.selectorName === 'pseudoElement') {
        throw new Error('Element, id and pseudo-element should not occur more then one time inside the selector');
      }
      it.selectors.push(prevSelector);
    }
    it.selectors.push({ selectorName: 'pseudoElement', selector: `::${value}` });
    return it;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Considering that I've detected some parts have very close functionality. But aggregation of ones is not possible for me because of their view scope.

In the code you could find a few differences

```
     UNIQUE_METHOD_NAME
     UNIQUE_SELECTOR_NAME
     UNIQUE_ORDER_ID
     UNIQUE_SELECTOR_VALUE_FORMAT
```

in generally duplicated blocks (functions):

```
  UNIQUE_METHOD_NAME(value) {
    const it = new CssSelectorBuilder();
    it.selectors = this.selectors.slice();
    const prevSelector = it.selectors.pop();
    /// OPTIONAL PART
    if (prevSelector.selectorName === 'UNIQUE_SELECTOR_NAME') {
      throw new Error('Element, id and pseudo-element should not occur more then one time inside the selector');
    }
    /// optional part END
    if (it.order.slice(UNIQUE_ORDER_ID).includes(prevSelector.selectorName)) {
      throw new Error('Selector parts should be arranged in the following order: element, id, class, attribute, pseudo-class, pseudo-element');
    }
    it.selectors.push({ selectorName: 'UNIQUE_SELECTOR_NAME', selector: UNIQUE_SELECTOR_VALUE_FORMAT });
    return it;
  }
```

### Question:

Any ideas on how to simplify this solution?

### P.S.

I've tried to move it into separate function, but it appears a lot of `if` operators make the original view more readable than the refactored part.

Comment: Please describe in detail what your code is supposed to do and change the title to a brief description of that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, there was added tags also. NOTE: If you are not familiar with javascript I do not think you can figure out how to simplify it with function binding for example or other magic.

Comment: Whether or not we know JavaScript is not the issue here, one of the requirements of posting on code review is to explain what the code does so that we can better understand the question and provide a better code review. Please see our [guidelines on asking a good question on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). There are currently 2 Votes to Close this question, it will be closed when there are 5 votes to close.